# New SharePoint Library Dropdown is showing hidden Libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

The new SharePoint/Office Library Dropdown feature has started to appear on our sites.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=81990

https://m365log.com/onedrive/microsoft-onedrive-sharepoint-library-dropdown-menu/

When expanding this it is showing all Libraries in the site even ones which are hidden.

Do you know if there is a way to disable this feature or to ensure that hidden libraries are not shown?